# How can I effectively detect when a double becomes NaN?

Tags: java, debugging, floating-point

I'm working on a software and, at some point in the program, a double becomes NaN which destroys the entire program.

Can I get some help on how to debug a problem like this and how to find the actual line where a double is accidentally set to NaN?

Comment: Share your code  with us

Comment: My program consists of a LOT of code

Comment: so use the freaking built in debugger, serious, learn to google...

Comment: @ShaunWild, then use   [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I voted to reopen since this can appear like a lazy question from someone who doesn't know how to use a debugger, but tracing down NaNs in complex production code is actually something that often eludes a lot of debugging sessions and can require alternative techniques. But those IDE tags definitely needed to go, and this is more appropriately a question that includes the [floating-point] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Narrowing down where a `NaN` occurs can be quite difficult sometimes in a context doing very complex work. The author of Physically-Based Rendering documents a tricky case, for example, where his raytracer was slowed down to a crawl as a result of some expressions evaluating to `NaN` which caused an excessive amount of computation subsequently. These things can be quite tricky to spot, especially if it's an edge case that only occurs one in a million times.

A handy trick is to rely on the IEEE standard where a variable compared to itself will return false if its value is `NaN`. This may not work on all compilers so you may want to make sure it does before you sprinkle assertions, but...

```
boolean is_nan(double val)
{
    return val != val;
}
```

In Java we don't need this trick, however. We already have `isNan` in `java.lang.Double`.

With this handy, you can narrow down where a NaN occurs through a process of elimination by doing sanity checks like:

```
double val = ...;
// after various arithmetical operations
assert !Double.isNan(val);
```

You can then work your way down (up?) and narrow down exactly what line of code is producing a NaN by adding more granular checks of this sort whenever you hit an assertion failure, taking note of which line of code in which the assertion fails. In very complex scenarios like the raytracer scenario cited where this might only occur one in a million times, this can be a lot quicker than trying to trace everything through a debugger.

Comment: I'll have a look through my code and apply this technique thanks!